# Double to String error in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, slider

How do I display the value from a custom range slider to the user as the user drags the knob?

---

**Context**

I am new to iOS dev, so please forgive me if I am missing something obvious. I am creating a custom range slider, and now I am at the point where I would like to display the value from the slider to the user in the UI as the user drags the knob.

For background, I have completed [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76433/how-to-make-a-custom-control-swift#comments) and am now attempting to take the values printed in the console and convert them into a readable string to display to the user. The values are printed via this function:

```
func rangeSliderValueChanged(rangeSlider: RangeSlider) {        
    print("Range slider value changed: (\(rangeSlider.lowerValue) \(rangeSlider.upperValue))")
}
```

Which is called in `viewDidLoad` in the `ViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(rangeSlider)

    rangeSlider.addTarget(self, action: "rangeSliderValueChanged:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)        
}
```

`ValueChanged` is in an override of `continueTrackingWithTouch` in `RangeSlider.swift`:

```
override func continueTrackingWithTouch(touch: UITouch,
    withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    // .. other stuff

    self.sendActionsForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    return true
}
```

---

**My Attempt**

At this point I figured the way to solve this was to add a text field in the view, then update the text field with the value from the slider.

I created a text field in `viewDidLoad`:

```
var lowNumber: UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200.00, height: 40.00))

override func viewDidLoad() {

    lowNumber.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    lowNumber.text = "some string"
    lowNumber.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Line

    self.view.addSubview(lowNumber)

    // .. more stuff
}
```

Then I tried to change the text field string in the `rangeSliderValueChanged` function:

```
func rangeSliderValueChanged(rangeSlider: RangeSlider) {
    lowNumber.text = rangeSlider.lowerValue
}
```

---

**Error**

At this point I encountered an error which states:

`Cannot assign a value of type 'Double' to a value of type 'String?'`

Double is used in the `RangeSlider` class such as:

```
class RangeSlider: UIControl {
    // .. stuff

    var lowerValue: Double = 0.2 {
        didSet {
            updateLayerFrames()
        }
    }

    // .. more stuff
}
```

This is where I am stuck, and the googling I have done on converting a double to a string has left me wondering how I could apply those solutions to my case. More fundamentally, I am wondering if I am approaching the problem in the right fashion.

---

**Question**

How do I solve the problem of displaying the value from the slider to the user? Do I need to use a different type of layer than `UITextField`? Have I approached the problem correctly, or would you recommend a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the number to `String`. For example:

```
lowNumber.text = "\(rangeSlider.lowerValue)"
```

Comment: Ha. So simple, yet was difficult for me as a beginner. Thank you very much @Adam.